# Unknown column field while storing value by attach() method Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

i want to store multiple checkbox value by using 
`attach(`) method.But the problem is:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_id' in 'field list'
>   (SQL: insert into `size_products` (`category_id`, `product_id`) values
>   (small, 5))

My Table `size_products` Structure like this (`size_id`, `product_id`) .But dont know where came from `category_id` column

Here is My Models:

```
   //Size Model


class Size extends Model
    {

        public function Products()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'size_products','product_id','size_id');
        }
    }


/////// Product Model


class Product extends Model
{
    public function Categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_products');
    }
    public function Colors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'color_products');
    }
    public function Sizes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'size_products');
    }
    public function FirstImage(){
        $data = explode(',',$this->images);
        return $data[0];
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller :

```
      $product = new Product();
 $product->name= $request->input('name');
 $product->model= $request->input('model');
 $product->save();
            $product->Categories()->attach($request->input('categories_id'));
            foreach ($request->sizes as $size){
                $product->Sizes()->attach($size);
            }
            foreach ($request->colors as $color){
                $product->Colors()->attach($color);
            }
```

Database :

```
Schema::create('size_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('size_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('size_id')->references('id')->on('sizes')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: please give me any solution

Answer (score 0):

Fix these relation in your product model

```
public function Sizes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'size_products');
}

public function Colors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class, 'color_products');
}
```